# HTML: i want to have 3 divs in one html script and all with 100% height and width

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok now explanation time.. :)
suppose 1 div is there with 100% of page cover and as i scroll down 2nd div immediately take it's place and same case with third.
i think the answer of this question is quite lengthy but it would be very helpful for me as well as others who will come in search of this answer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So basically all of the divs cover 100% of the viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example the page does what you want with the mouse wheel. You may want to add support for the scroll bar, and keyboard uo/down arrows, etc. This is from [Vaibs_Cool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953652/scroll-a-full-page-height-up-or-down-with-jquery-javascript)

```
$(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        // find currently visible div :
        div = -1;
        divs.each(function(i){
            if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                div = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
            div--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
            div++;
        }
        //console.log(div, dir, divs.length);
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/JqU2T/8/

http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/JqU2T/8/embedded/result/