# Scrolling full pages on site using JS/JQ - looking to override behaviour when using web-buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I used some code I found here: [scroll a full page height up or down with jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953652/scroll-a-full-page-height-up-or-down-with-jquery-javascript)
From the link on answer 3. By setting the DIV ID to 'page1', 'page2' etc. it scrolls a full page at a time.

It works ok, but 'takes over' all scrolling. I need to be able to have the user press a CTA button, and it scroll down 3 pages. But it scrolls down 3 pages, then back up 2 (because that's 'current page + 1').

Here's the code for forcing a full page scroll:

```
var pages = 7;
var currentpage = 1;
if (document.location.hash) { currentpage = parseInt(document.location.hash.replace('#', '')); }

var nextpage = currentpage + 1; if (nextpage > pages) { nextpage = pages; }
var prevpage = currentpage - 1; if (prevpage < 1) { prevpage = 1; }

var animatingup = false;
var animatingdown = false;

jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) {

if (animatingup==true) { return; }
if (animatingdown==true) { return; }
nextpage = currentpage + 1; if (nextpage > pages) { nextpage = pages; }
prevpage = currentpage - 1; if (prevpage < 1) { prevpage = 1; }

if (animatingup == false) {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop()+jQuery(window).height()>=jQuery("#page"+(nextpage)).offset().top+50) {
        if (nextpage > currentpage) {
            var p2 = jQuery( "#page"+(nextpage) );
            var pageheight = p2.position().top;
            animatingdown = true;
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 800, function() { currentpage = nextpage; animatingdown = false; document.location.hash = currentpage;});
            return;
        }
    }
}

if (animatingdown == false) {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop()<=jQuery("#page"+(currentpage)).offset().top-50) {
        if (prevpage < currentpage) {
            var p2 = jQuery( "#page"+(currentpage) );
            var pageheight = p2.position().top-jQuery(window).height();
            animatingup = true;
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 800, function() { currentpage = prevpage; animatingup = false; document.location.hash = currentpage;});
            return;
        }
    }
}
});
```

I thought I could just force the page/DIV ID number to change with this:

```
jQuery('#ctabut').click(function(){
    currentpage = 6;
});
```

but it still scrolls to DIV ID 'page7' then back up. Any ideas on a) a better way to scroll full pages, b) how to override the scroll on button click c) how to implement the JS code ONLY on the home page (it's a wordpress site) - really appreciated.

It's only a dev site so can't point to it. My code skills are very limited - so feel free to speak to me like I'm simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as often happens, I resort to the forums and then work it out.

If I replace my 'button code' jQuery with this:

```
jQuery('#ctabut').click(function(){
    var p2 = jQuery( "#page7" );
    var pageheight = p2.position().top;
    animatingup = true;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 800, function() { currentpage = 7; animatingup = false; document.location.hash = 7;});
});
```

it sets all the variables properly and prevents the 'bounce back'.

I post the answer in case anyone as noob as me wants to create their own simple 'whole page scroller' without using a big pre-made library like fullpage.js