# How can I make the wheel scrolling distance 100% of page height?

Tags: javascript, scroll, height, mouse

Hey guys I have a page and I'm trying to capture the mouse wheel so when someone is at the top and scrolls just once the page scrolls to the 100% of what the browser shows sorry I have no idea how to explain this just visit [Mega](https://mega.nz) and scroll down once and you will see what I mean. Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scroll a full page height up or down with jQuery/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953652/scroll-a-full-page-height-up-or-down-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Thanks didn't see that

Comment: @yuriy636 the possible duplicate is tagged jQuery, this question is not.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete implementation, by any stretch, but should be enough to get you started.

HTML

```
<div id="head">Your top page...</div>
<div>All other content...</div>
```

CSS

```
#head {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Javascript

```
var head = document.getElementById('head');
head.addEventListener("wheel", handleMouseWheel);

function handleMouseWheel (event) {
  window.scrollTo(0, head.scrollHeight);
}
```

See working http://codepen.io/jtrumbull/pen/vXNREy