# Scrolling 100vh sections on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a general question, but I'm trying to find some code examples and the term used for this type of behavior and how to implement it.

Example: https://pixelheads.nl/

Each section is fully scrolled into view on scroll.

Comment: dunno what it's called. "single/one page scroll" maybe? fullpage.js is a library that will do it http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage

Comment: Thanks, can it be done with a specified section, when I try my own, it doesn't work with other sections, example: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/7b2w82x2/

Comment: @Snorlax all sections have to be within the same wrapper as stated [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#required-html-structure).

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the javascript of the example, we can see that the page works with all the elements, one after the another, but when he puts the command `overflow:hidden;` the page not shows the scroll bar.

To give the effect for all the pages, there is an effect "translate3d" and the page "scrolls".
To show the second page:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, -622px, 0px);
```

For the third:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, -1244px, 0px);
```

I dont found the command into the page to get the mouse wheel, but you can put a event that will be fired when you scroll the page.

```
$("body").bind("mousewheel", function(e)
{
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta; // give you the direction
    // here you apply the transform on the page.
});
```

I'm not sure if this example page is using any framework, but i found this question that can help you, if you dont want to do from the beginning. The library mencioned at this question is the same as Michael Coker commentary (alvarotrigo.com/fullPage).

> [scroll a full page height up or down with jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953652/scroll-a-full-page-height-up-or-down-with-jquery-javascript/19009634)

I know that the response is not complete, but can give you some directions.

Comment: Thanks, can it be done with a specified section, when I try my own, it doesn't work with other sections, example: jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/7b2w82x2

Comment: You need to put your code into the section, like here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b2w82x2/1/)

Comment: If you want to insert the header of your page or any static object, use `position:fixed` like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b2w82x2/2/)